# Using NodeJS for serving content, but responseType is always ""

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server

I'm trying to develop a simple API using Node.js, im using XMLHttpRequest on client and the data is being served well, but I'm not being able to set a Response-Type header to my response.

So the Response-Type on xhr object on client is getting always:
`responseType:""`.

Even when I set:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':"application/javascript"});
```

It happens to both POST and GET situations.

-
My server.js:

```
var https = require('https'),
    options = {
        key : fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
        cert : fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
    },
    server = https.createServer(options);

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
   switch(req.method){
       case "GET":
           res.writeHead(200, {
               'accept': '*/*',
               'content-type': "application/javascript"
           });
           res.end('console.log("API GET Received")');
           break;
       case "POST":
           res.writeHead(200, {
               'content-type': "application/javascript"
           });
           req.on("data", function(data){
               console.log(data.toString("utf8"));
           });

           res.end('console.log("API POST received")');
           break;
       case "PUT":
           break;
       case "DELETE":
           break;
    }
    req.on('error', function(err) {console.log(err);});
    return;
}
server.listen(443);
```

-
The XHR object logged on client:

```
...
readyState:4
response:'console.log("API POST received")'
responseText:'console.log("API POST received")'
responseType:"" //This should be: "application/javascript"
...
```

By the way:

```
node -v:       v6.5.0
npm --version: 3.10.6
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) describes (and should be *set* by you) the JavaScript data-type of the `response` property: `arraybuffer`, `blob`, `document`, `json`, or `text`. You have text here; if you want to have the response value interpreted as an `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` instead of text, you will need to set the `responseType` property before you send your request.

In no case is `application/javascript` a valid value for the `responseType` property. What type JavaScript value would you expect to be present in the `response` property in that case? It is already a string.

If you merely want to read the `Content-Type` response header in the client, use [`getReponseHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader) method after the request completes:

```
var contentTypeHeader = xhr.getReponseHeader("Content-Type");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the problem, but it looks like the program doesn't write any header in the POST case.

```
  case "POST":
       res.writeHead(200, {
       });
```

should read something like

```
   case "POST":
       res.writeHead(200, {
           'content-type': "application/javascript"
       });
```

(or maybe initialize it before the switch)

Comment: That was my mistake when pasting the code here sorry... Edited already, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting the header only on the GET request and not on POST.

Could that be the issue?

Comment: That was my mistake when pasting the code here sorry... Edited already, thanks!